# How to error handle string to float conversion

Tags: rust

This is a very simple question but I can't seem to solve it. I have a string that I'd like to convert to a float. I want to catch any error in this conversion as well.

```
let str = "10.0"
let f: f32 = str.parse().unwrap();
```

How can I catch errors of the string is `""` or `dog`. I was trying to use a match expression with Some and None, but I'm not sure that correct as I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you show your `match` attempt? Did you remove the `unwrap()` call? Note that `parse()` returns a `Result` so it'd be `Ok` and `Err` rather than `Some` and `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parse` returns a `Result`, not an `Option`, so you should use `Ok` and `Err` instead of `Some` and `None`:

```rust
let str = "10.0";
let f: f32 = match str.parse() {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(_) => 0.0 // or whatever error handling
};
```